Error Installing grpcio 1.66.1 with Poetry: PEP 517 Build Issue
I'm trying to install dependencies for my Python project using Poetry, but I keep encountering an error when it attempts to downgrade grpcio from 1.68.0 to 1.66.1. Here's what happens when I run poetry install:
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 1 update, 0 removals

  - Downgrading grpcio (1.68.0 -> 1.66.1): Preparing...

After that, I receive the following error:
Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with grpcio (1.66.1) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --no-cache-dir --use-pep517 "grpcio (==1.66.1)"'.

It seems like the issue is related to grpcio not supporting PEP 517 builds in version 1.66.1. However, I’m not sure how to proceed with resolving this problem while still using Poetry.

Haven't met this problem with poetry@1.8.4

@keria this worked for me. but when i uninstall it and try to install again i get this error message.

github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/34998 - if you're using an arm64 architecture processor, and something like alpine linux that uses the musl C library instead of glibc, it might just not be finding an available wheel since it doesn't exist. I had a poetry error message like this where PEP 517 was not the real issue. Switching from python:3.11-alpine in my Dockerfile to python:3.11-slim fixed my case.
